# php - Comparing and printing same values in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to compare the data in an array like the one below and merge the same ones.

```
Array (    [0] => Array
       (
           [0] => 2019-10-21
           [1] => Remzi
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [0] => 2019-10-21
           [1] => Ahmet
      )

   [2] => Array
       (
           [0] => 2019-10-14
           [1] => Ali
       ) )
```

I want to get output like this:

```
2019-10-21, Remzi - Ahmet (Same birtday) <br>
2019-10-14, Ali (different birtday)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please mention what did you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this,

```
$birthday_dic = [];
foreach($birthdays as $birthday){
    $birthday_dic[$birthday[0]][] = $birthday[1];
}
$birthday_dic = array_map(function($v){return join(" - ",$v);},$birthday_dic);
print_r($birthday_dic);
```

Comment: I can't print this with foreach. How I can?
`
foreach ($birthday_dic as $birthday){ 
    fputcsv($file, $birthday);
}`

this one didnt work

Comment: If you want to write a csv file, remove the line with `array_map` above. Refer to [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)